# Eclipse Kepler SR-1 & Subclipse plugin installation error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

My env:

Eclipse Kepler SR 1
Oracle jdk: jdk1.7.0_45
Windows 8.

Help | Eclipse Marketplace | Popular 
Clicked on Subclipse 1.8.22 install
Takes a very long time on 'Confirm Selected Features' page
[image]

Eventually comes back with the following page:
[image]

Clicking confirm shows the following:
[image]

Saw a post on the web about adding the following to eclipse.ini

`-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Didn't help.

Comment: subclipse.tigris.org appears to be down or running extremely slowly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tigris is down. There was a planned maintenance period announced. Should be online again in a few hours.

Surprised it even got as far as it did.

UPDATE: tigris.org should be back online now.

One other note, the current version of Subclipse is 1.10.x.  This is not the version you get via the Eclipse Marketplace yet.  You can however enter the update site URL for this version directly into Eclipse.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x